# Is there a way to make a container have the styles width: 100% - constant

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical nav-bar that takes that is a set 250px. I made the nav-bar a template on django and  now I am looking to create a container div that fills the rest of the page. My question is **how do I get this div to be the width of the entire page minus this nav-bar**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it with grid. Set two columns, one 250px and give the second rest of space.

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}

.grid{
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 250px 1fr;
height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;
}

.nav {
 width:250px;
 background-color: green;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="nav"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much that is a very helpful solution it also works with my media query that makes the nav-bar horizontal at the top. I suppose i can use grid-template-rows! Thanks